# Библиотека Unirest. Как получить ответ в формате base64url?

Tags: java, http

Есть апи-метод, который по переданным данным(JSON) возвращает строку в base64url.
Возвращается просто строка, не в джейсоне или хмле.
Как с помощью unirest получить эту строчку?
Пытался вот таким образом:

```
HttpResponse<JsonNode> jsonResponse
            = Unirest.post(url)
            .header("content-type", "application/json")
            .body(map)
            .asJson();
```

Но приходит ответ с хедерами:

```
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Length: 80
Keep-Alive: timeout=60
Connection: keep-alive
```

И пустым телом. Если убрать хедер с типом контента, то в ответе:

```
{"status":415,"error":"Unsupported Media Type","message":"","path":""}
```

Answer (score 0):

Нужно использовать .asString() вместо .asJson().
Все же полезно иногда заглядывать в доку :)

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).